# How to make Scrollable image on axes Matlab?

Tags: matlab

Is there a way to make axes in Matlab scrollable because I am trying to show image on it which is either getting scaled down to small size or I am able to make it stretch to axes dimension. Is there a way to make it scrollable image?

Comment: What's wrong with using the zoom/pan controls within the figure toolbar?

Comment: @Suever how do I do that

Comment: Using the standard toolbar with the magnifying glass and the hand? http://www.mathworks.com/help/releases/R2015b/matlab/creating_guis/fig_toolbar_std8b_fh.png

Comment: @Suever I have made my own GUI I want to implement on that. Thanks.

Comment: See directions here: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_guis/creating-toolbars-for-programmatic-guis.html